# Sequelize.js updateAttributes does not save partial data

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

When updating data partially, data does not persist. For example, I call the following (where data is an object):

```
account.updateAttributes(data).then(function(updated) {
        res.send(updated);
        return next();

})['catch'](function(err) {
       log.error(err);
           return next(new restify.InternalError(err.message));
});
```

Comment: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4346

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue was caused because I was explicitly setting the object properties using the `beforeValidate` method. By removing this, I was able to update the field.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to pass updated data to next middleware. But you used `res.send(updated)`. It terminates middleware and return the response.

You can use to pass the updated data with the following;

```
account.updateAttributes(data).then(function(updated) {
  req.updatedAccount = updated;
  return next();
})['catch'](function(err) {
  log.error(err);
  return next(new restify.InternalError(err.message));
});
```

So you can attach the updated data to your request object and send with it to next middleware. And you can use the data in next middleware with `req.updatedAccount`.

I hope it works.